# Adding a REGEXP in my query

Tags: php

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM ".$this->table_name."
        WHERE position  RLIKE '^([0-9]+>){1,1}$' AND c_group    =      '".$this->Group."'
        ORDER BY c_name";

RLIKE '^[0-9]+>$'
```

Merge the below term in y query... i am getting errors.

Comment: Add actual result, expected result and people might be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify much information. I'm assuming you're using MySQL, in which case RLIKE doesn't accept PCREs, it accepts Henry Spencer's RegExs. I don't believe your RegEx is valid.